# Adding custom item to Table View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu, cell, menuitem

I am trying to add a custom item to my table view menu which is found in `ViewController`. I've implemented all necessary methods but my item still does not show up. If I use default items, like "copy" everything works fine. I left out performAction method, because I don't really know what to add there, but copy action showed up without it. Could you tell me what I am getting wrong? I've attached my code to add custom menu item below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let item = UIMenuItem(title: "Block and Report", action: #selector(MessageViewController.blockAndReport(_:)))

    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()

    var newItems = menu.menuItems
        ?? [UIMenuItem]()
    newItems.append(item)
    menu.menuItems = newItems ...}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if action == #selector(MessageViewController.blockAndReport(_:)) {
        return true
    }


    return false
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {

    //I don't really know what to add here
}

func blockAndReport(sender: AnyObject?) {

    print("Hello")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Custom Item to your super view as sub view

use this line

```
self.tableview.addSubview(item)
```

Comment: item is of type UIMenuItem, addSubview requires type view.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had to set up the TableViewCell class and connect it to my cell and in this class I had to implement method blockAndReport. Now everything works fine. I conclude that you can't use methods for your table menu items from the same class.